# Creating custom django shortcode

Tags: django

how can i create my custom shortcode? 
 I did install 'django-shortcodes' application added it inside project settings loaded it inside my template... what next? 
 I need to create my personal short code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are talking about https://github.com/martey/django-shortcodes

You will need to fork it and add new parsers in the shortcode directory.

See here :

https://github.com/martey/django-shortcodes/tree/master/shortcodes/parsers